# jQuery Ajax POST form not posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have no idea why my form isn't posting and instead just reloads the page.

I can do this with `$.ajax({type:GET})`. But it just doesn't feel right doing it this way as all my script post data to the database.

I also tried adding `$('#status-form').serialize()` and `'status=' + status_value` to `$.ajax({data:})`. But doesn't work. Just refreshes the page and submits nothing to the database.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit',function() {
    var project_id_value=$(this).closest('tr').find('.project_id').text();
    $('#popup').show();
    $('#popup').load('scripts/form.php');

$(document).on('click',".bttt", function(){
    var status_value=$('#status option:selected').val();
    var formData = $('#status-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:POST,
        url:'scripts/change-status.php?project_id=' + project_id_value,
        data:formData,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)},
        });
    });
return false;
});
```

form:

```
<form method="post" id="status-form">
<select name="status" id="status">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">Closed</option>
</select>
<button class="bttt">Hello</button>
</form>
```

EDIT:

I have fixed the typo mistake. Still have the same problem

***SOLUTION:***

I found the solution to this why browser use to refresh and do nothing. Since I'm using firefox and firefox takes any button in a form as a submit button. When I clicked the button it was used to POST the form before reaching to $.ajax({success:}). What I had to do is to give the button a `type="button"`

Comment: Your PHP has nothing to do with your question. Please post the *rendered* HTML, not the PHP source.

Comment: Are you sure no errors are showing in your console?

Comment: The nested click function is one of the things that is make this hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Console show no errors. I can't see the network activity since the page reloads after clicking the button.

Comment: add error: function(xhr, status, message){alert(message);}

Comment: I found the solution to this. Since I'm using firefox and firefox takes any button in a form as a submit button. When i clicked the button it was used to post the form before reaching to $.ajax({success:}). What I had to do is to give the button a `type="button"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type has to be represented as a string. Thus, it's `type: 'POST'`.

Comment: Or `method: "POST"` for the latest jquery versions.

Comment: Also, I get no alert on success

Answer (score 1):

Just the form submission, below code should work

```
$(document).on('click',".bttt", function(){
    var status_value=$('#status option:selected').val();
    var formData = $('#status-form').serialize();
    var project_id_value = 123;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'change-status.php?project_id=' + project_id_value,
        data:formData,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```